# How can I fix the sigma value in an Arima model

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I'd like to fix the Variance value in an Arima model.  How can I specify this.  From what I can tell it cannot be set through the fixed parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine you may have to write and optimize your own likelihood. This does not appear like a common problem; I have never encountered something like this. Perhaps you would like to add a paragraph describing why you want to do this?

Comment: @StephanKolassa My model has been built already using an external application (Multiple models using Markov Switching).  Just trying to take the output from the application and bring them into R.  The application has already computed the Variance for me.

Comment: Uh, I'm afraid I don't understand. If you have multiple models, each one would come with its own (residual) variance estimate. And more to the point, multiple ARIMA models would already come with their own AR and MA parameter estimates. So I don't really understand why you would want to fit an ARIMA model (with given orders?) with a pre-specified residual variance.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I don't want to fit.  I want to predict using a specified model.  I have my AR, MA and Residual.  I want to create the model with these specifications in R and predict using it.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be an ugly hack, but it should work.

Load the `forecast` library and create an ARIMA fit of the specified order so we have a template.

```
library(fit)
fit <- Arima(WWWusage,order=c(3,0,1))
```

Examine the components of `fit`.

```
names(fit)
```

Change them to match the model you want to forecast - the variance is in the `sigma2` component:

```
fit$coef <- structure(c(1,-.2,1,0.2,100),.Names=names(fit$coef))
fit$sigma2 <- 20
```

And forecast, using `forecast.Arima()`:

```
forecast(fit,h=20)
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

[image: forecast]

You may also want to look at `arima.sim()` and feed the residual variance into the `rand.gen` innovations generator.